# How to use express, ssh2 and shellJSNodeJS

Tags: express, libssh2

Trying to use SSH2 and express for executing the command from remote server and view the output in the browser.When I executed the below command, I received the output of "uptime" in console log. but I am not able to display them in the browser.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();
var test = function(req,res,next)
{
  conn.on('ready', function() 
  {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) 
    {
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.on('close', function(code, signal) 
      {
       console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
       conn.end();
      }).on('data', function(data) 
      {
       console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
       res.write(data)
      }).stderr.on('data', function(data) 
      {
       console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
      });
    });
 }).connect
      ({
          host: '192.168.1.10',
          port: 22,
          username: 'username',
          password: 'password'
      });
}
app.use('/', test)
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: In order to use shelljs on the server you need to remotely execute the script there. What I would suggest to you is to execute the command directly there with ssh `conn.exec( "cat /var/log/some_file" , function...`

Comment: I tried to execute ssh2, but I am unable to get the out put in browser. I have edited the question and added my code

Comment: You need to terminate your request `res.end()` in `stream.on("close"...` callback.

Comment: var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();
var test = function(req,res,next)
{
conn.on('ready', function() {
console.log('Client :: ready');
conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
if (err) throw err;
stream.on('data', function(data) {
res.write(data)
res.end()
})
})
}).connect
({
host: '192.168.1.6',
port: 22,
username: 'username',
password: 'password'
});
}
app.use('/', test)
app.listen(3000)
Its working but getting below err 
throw er;// Unhandled 'error' event
Error: write after end

Comment: @drinchev   Its working but getting below error 
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: write after end
 at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:625:15)
 at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:620:10)
 at Channel.<anonymous> (Express1\server.js:12:5)
 at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
 at Channel.emit (events.js:211:7)
 at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
 at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
 at Channel.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
 at SSH2Stream.<anonymous> (node_modules\ssh2\lib\Channel.js:166:15)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

Answer (score 0):

moved the data into variable and used the res.write() after the exec function.

Now I am using ssh2-utils(wrapper of ssh2), which made the script simpler